# Android bottom sheet dialog how to set scrim animation

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetdialog

I noticed that by default, when a bottom sheet dialog is shown, the scrim just pop up without any animation, which is not a good user experience. So I was wondering how to show the scrim with animation. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = *Your animation here*`(
For example, R.style.myAnimation

```
<style name="myAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/down</item>
</style>
```

)

Comment: I tried to define my custom `enter/exit` animation for the scrim and used it in the `onCreate` method of my `bottomSheetDialogFragment`：`dialog?.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = R.style.scrimAnimation`. As it turned out, the scrim is now not popping up suddenly but is still not working as expected. For example, even if the animation duration is given the value `3000ms`, the actual duration is obviously less than`3000`.